# How can I use Javascript RegExp to escape brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to use the following RegExp to escape the brackets and things inside. 
Here is the example string:

`hjdsoghbesi (saeogbesor) serogberso ersberawsewf(edsrgb) sfdrobersb ouersber`

I want the result code to be

`hjdsoghbesi  serogberso ersberawsewf sfdrobersb ouersber`

I tried to use the following:

`myString.replace(/\(.*\)/g,"")`

However, this focused on the very first open bracket and the very last close bracket and gave me:

`hjdsoghbesi  sfdrobersb ouersber`

How can I achieve the result that I wanted?

If you intend to answer, please tell me why your RegExp can achieve my purpose as I am unfamiliar with RegExp.

Comment: What do you mean by escape? Do you mean remove?

Comment: When your regexp is not working it's always a good idea to try an on-line regexp tester such as regex101. In addition to testing your regexp it will describe it to you in human terms. In this case, the description for the `*` is: *Quantifier: \* Between zero and unlimited times, as **many times as possible**, giving back as needed [greedy]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-greedy quantifiers:

```js
var str = "hjdsoghbesi (saeogbesor) serogberso ersberawsewf(edsrgb) sfdrobersb ouersber";
console.log(str.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, ""));
```

`*` is greedy, it will match as many characters as possible.

`*?` is lazy, it will match as few as possible.

Comment: I see that you used "?" to prevent the problem. Can you explain why that happens like that?

Comment: What about nested brackets?

Comment: @stdob-- I assume no nesting. Regex can't handle arbitrarily deep nesting anyways.

Comment: *Can you explain why that happens like that?* It happens like that because that is what `*?` tells it to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Oriol's answer, I see the following possibility. Use `[^\)]` instead of `.`: `myString.replace(/\([^\)]*\)/g,"")`. `[^\)]` matches all characters except for `)`. `[]` lists matching characters and `^` at this point inverts them so that all except for the listed ones are matched.

Comment: No need to escape the `)` inside the character set.